# Google App Engine Search API (Python) - search on multiple search indexes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api, google-app-engine-python

Is it possible to perform a search on multiple indexes using App Engine's search api in order to leverage the search.Query options for both indexes?

For example, `search.Index(a)` has Book documents and `search.Index(b)` has Movie documents. Then, the following query:

```
search.Query(
   query_string="Dog",
   options=search.QueryOptions(
      limit=10,
      offset=0,
      sort_options=search.SortOptions(
         match_scorer=search.MatchScorer())))`
```

would return the first 10 results from the Book and Movie indexes combined that best match the query string "Dog".

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_adv/lesson3), it seems to suggest the search api is limited only to one search index but I'm wondering if there was a workaround.